# A question about PyQt5: What is the effect of the '&' character in the second parameter of function Qaction()?

Tags: pyqt5

Here is the code:

```
class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):               

        exitAct = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)
        exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAct.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        self.statusBar()

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAct)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 1080, 720)
        self.setWindowTitle('Simple menu')    
        self.show()
```

I don't know whether the '&' character in '&Exit' and '&File' is necessary. The script works when I delete '&'. If it's necessary, what's its effect?

Comment: It denotes a “shortcut” key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I delete ‘&’ character and run the script again,  I can still use 'Ctrl +Q'  as a shortcut for the 'Exit' action. So, does this mean that the '&' character is just a denotation without real effect? Is it just for good readability？

Comment: @ent those are called "mnemonics", were introduced in early OS (Windows 3.11 already supported them) but are still used; the & is *before* the letter that can be used to directly trigger that specific menu action with the keyboard when the menu is shown: open the menu, press "E" on the keyboard and you'll trigger the "&Exit" action. Note that those are also used for buttons and "buddies" ([`setBuddy()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#setBuddy)), using the Alt modifier. In your case, press Alt+F will open your "&File" menu. Note that these shortcuts will be underlined as soon as you press Alt.

Comment: See also: [QShortcut](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html#details) and [QtGui.qt_set_sequence_auto_mnemonic](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#qt_set_sequence_auto_mnemonic).